# Como calcular valor + sum(valor) dentro de um select

Tags: sql-server, select, sum

Olá eu pretendo fazer um select nesse sentido:

```
select NUM_PEDIDO, VALOR, ((VALOR/ sum(VALOR)) * 100) as PORC from PEDIDO
```

**Obviamente** isso me retornará esse erro: (... is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.)

Preciso de um select que retorne o Numero do pedido, o valor, e a porcentagem dele sobre o total.

A ideia aqui é calcular o percentual do valor do pedido sobre o total dos pedidos, por exemplo em um mês fiz 1.000,00 reais em pedidos, e um determinado pedido desse mês é de 100,00 reais, significa que ele equivale a 10% dos pedidos desse mês.

Mas gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de calcular esse percentual em um select no SQL Server

Comment: Tente com subselect: `select NUM_PEDIDO, VALOR, ((VALOR/ (SELECT sum(VALOR) FROM PEDIDO)) * 100) as PORC from PEDIDO`

Comment: isso seria bem ruim, pq o sql vai acabar computando o `sum`, ainda que seja o mesmo, para cada registro da tabela, que pode deixar bem lento. Sugiro computar a soma e atribuir a uma variável, e depois usar essa variável no select seguinte que vai dividir valor pela soma. Isso pode ser posto numa procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você quer é percentual de uma parte sobre um todo. É algo simples de implementar utilizando a função de janela SUM.

Para calcular o percentual de cada item do pedido sobre o total do pedido, experimente

```
-- código #1
SELECT NUM_PEDIDO, VALOR, 
       (100.0 * VALOR / sum(VALOR) over (partition by NUM_PEDIDO)) as PORC 
  from PEDIDO;
```

Caso queira calcular percentual de cada item sobre a somatória de todos os pedidos, experimente

```
-- código #2
SELECT NUM_PEDIDO, VALOR, 
       (100.0 * VALOR / sum(VALOR) over ()) as PORC 
  from PEDIDO;
```

No artigo [Funções de janela (window functions)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/14/funcoes-de-janela-window-functions/) você encontra detalhes sobre a cláusula OVER(), que é a peça chave. Se quiser aprofundar no estudo das funções de janela, avalie adquirir o livro [T-SQL Window Functions: For data analysis and beyond](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/14/funcoes-de-janela-window-functions/).